# Converting 2 bytes to Short in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, short

I'm trying to convert two bytes into an unsigned short so I can retrieve the actual server port value. I'm basing it off from this [protocol specification](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Master_Server_Query_Protocol) under Reply Format. I tried using [BitConverter.ToUint16()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint16(v=vs.110).aspx) for this, but the problem is, it doesn't seem to throw the expected value. See below for a sample implementation:

```
int bytesRead = 0;

while (bytesRead < ms.Length)
{
    int first = ms.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
    int second = ms.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
    int third = ms.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
    int fourth = ms.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
    int port1 = ms.ReadByte();
    int port2 = ms.ReadByte();
    int actualPort = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] {(byte)port1 , (byte)port2 }, 0);
    string ip = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}:{4}-{5} = {6}", first, second, third, fourth, port1, port2, actualPort);
    Debug.WriteLine(ip);
    bytesRead += 6;
}
```

Given one sample data, let's say for the two byte values, I have 105 & 135, the expected port value after conversion should be 27015, but instead I get a value of 34665 using BitConverter.

Am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you reverse the values in the BitConverter call, you should get the expected result:

```
int actualPort = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] {(byte)port2 , (byte)port1 }, 0);
```

On a little-endian architecture, the low order byte needs to be second in the array. And as lasseespeholt points out in the comments, you would need to reverse the order on a big-endian architecture. That could be checked with the [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) property. Or it might be a better solution overall to use [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329627%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) (convert the value first and then call that method to put the bytes in the correct order regardless of the endianness).

Comment: Are you sure this will work if the application is run on a different architecture?

Comment: @lasseespeholt:  That's a good point.  It probably does need a check using [IsLittleEndian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx).  For a big-endian architecture, the order would need to be as given in the OP.

Comment: solution from @BrokenGlass  ushort value2 = (ushort)(port1 + (port2 << 8)); should be preferred in speed critical situations as bitconverter can and allocating the extra array can be slow.

Answer (score 13):

BitConverter is doing the right thing, you just have low-byte and high-byte mixed up - you can verify using a bitshift manually:

```
byte port1 = 105;
byte port2 = 135;

ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] { (byte)port1, (byte)port2 }, 0);
ushort value2 = (ushort)(port1 + (port2 << 8)); //same output
```

Comment: +1 for the "manual" approach. In my opinion `BitConverter` does way to many checks and an endian check which can break the code.

Comment: from your solution: ushort value2 = (ushort)(port1 + (port2 << 8)); //same output  this is the way to go,  in most cases we need this type of conversion for a large volume of bytes and speed is likely to be an issue.  I am currently using this in imaging applications.  Overhead of creating the array and using bitconverter can be huge.

Comment: Lest anyone else goes down the same path I did.  Arithmetic operations in C# on anything less than 16 bits get converted to 16 bits to avoid overflow during the operation.  Hence the value2 operation converts port1 and the (port2 << 8) to ints, adds them together, and then he casts it back to a ushort.  So @shelypereira may be correct that BitConverter has overhead, so does the basic math, its just invisible.  See, this stack overflow link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065287/why-is-ushort-ushort-equal-to-int

Answer (score 11):

To work on both little and big endian architectures, you must do something like:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    actualPort = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] {(byte)port2 , (byte)port1 }, 0);
else
    actualPort = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] {(byte)port1 , (byte)port2 }, 0);
```