# Why is DateTime.Now.Year an int and not a ushort

Tags: .net, types

In the .Net framework DateTime structure, the Year is defined as an int (which is really A System.Int32). However, the MSDN documentation says that the value will always be [between 1 and 9999](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx). Thus, a ushort (System.UInt16) is more than adequate to store the value and takes up half the space. So why is it an int and not a ushort?

There is an implicit conversion from ushort to int so there is no casting that needs to be done to do integer arithmetic on the Year.

I realize this is a micro-optimization issue and thus not very important. I am just curious.

Comment: It is *not* an optimization.  Bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065287/why-is-ushort-system-uint16-ushort-equal-to-int-system-int32/10157517#10157517

Comment: Even with a `ushort`, we'd be wasting the top two bits...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Thus, a ushort (System.UInt16) is more than adequate to store the value and takes up half the space.

Where do you think that "space" is being wasted? `DateTime` doesn't store each component in a separate field anyway. If *you're* storing the year somewhere, feel free to cast it to a `ushort` - and cast `Month` to a `byte`, etc.

Note that `ushort` isn't CLS-compliant, which is probably the reason for it. There are a *lot* of properties which would make sense to be unsigned, such as `string.Length` etc... but the framework tries to be CLS-compliant where it can.

Answer (score 0):

- unit returns a Unsigned 16-bit integer
- Int returns a 32-bit integer.

I am assuming that the JIT Compiler takes advantage of the CPU architecture and therefore processing at 32bit would be more efficient than 16bit.  I believe there was a similar debate with VB6 when using Integers vs Longs (Bytes allocated vs Architecture Speed).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/08/15/451845.aspx