# why Short overflow causing compilation error but int overflow doesn’t

Tags: c#, int, type-conversion, short

why below mentioned code is causing compilation error

```
short value = short.MaxValue;  
value = value + 1;
```

But this is not

```
int value = int.MaxValue;  
value = value + 1;
```

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem/4347752#4347752

Comment: Note that quote formatting is not intended for code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10157517/17034

Comment: Be aware also that `value += 1` is allowed in both cases.