# How do I get simple UInt16 arithmetic to work?

Tags: c#, uint16

I've got some incredibly simple code. Three UInt16 variables. I can do simple assignments but it won't let me do simple arithmetic.

Here's the code

```
    UInt16 A = 1; // This is OK
    UInt16 B = 2; // This is OK
    UInt16 C = A * B; // Does NOT like this.
    C = A * 2; // Does NOT like this.
```

It highlights the A * B and reports that the A * B part *Cannot implicitly convert type "int" to "ushort". An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?*

Likewise for the   A * 2  part;

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to correct it?

Comment: Well, `A * B` is of type `Int32` (`int`). You have to cast: `UInt16 C = (UInt16) (A * B);` and `C = (UInt16)(A * 2);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is ushort + ushort equal to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065287/why-is-ushort-ushort-equal-to-int)