# short to byte conversion

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a short type into 2 bytes type for store in a byte array, here is the snippet thats been working well "so far".

```
if (type == "short")
{
   size = data.size;
   databuffer[index+1] = (byte)(data.numeric_data >> 8);
   databuffer[index] = (byte)(data.numeric_data & 255);
   return size;
}
```

Numeric_data is int type. It all worked well till i process the value 284 (decimal). It turns out that 284 >> 8 is 1 instead of 4.

The main goal is to have:

```
byte[0] = 28
byte[1] = 4
```

Comment: You are mixing up hexadecimal and decimal.

Comment: You are confusing decimal and binary.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749801/converting-2-bytes-to-short-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(short s)
{
    //return, if `short` can be cast to `byte` without overflow
    if (s <= byte.MaxValue) 
        return new byte[] { (byte)s };

    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    byte b = 0;
    //determine delta through the number of digits
    short delta = (short)Math.Pow(10, s.ToString().Length - 3);
    //as soon as byte can be not more than 3 digits length
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        //take first 3 (or 2, or 1) digits from the high-order digit
        short temp = (short)(s / delta);
        if (temp > byte.MaxValue) //if it's still too big
            delta *= 10;
        else //the byte is found, break the loop
        {
            b = (byte)temp;
            break;
        }
    }
    //add the found byte
    bytes.Add(b);
    //recursively search in the rest of the number
    bytes.AddRange(ToByteArray((short)(s % delta))); 
    return bytes.ToArray();
}
```

this recursive method does what the OP need with at least any positive `short` value.

Comment: this is the perfect answer, how you can do it with one line?

Comment: @ffenix: Like everyone said, this is the wrong way to do it. (Sorry, not one line here, my bad)

Comment: i still dont know why the wrong way, client is expecting that and no its not hex, visual studio shows me everything on decimal. so yes this is what i needed.

Comment: @ffenix please, check this another time....your original code did used bytes (like in the answer by ja72)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        short data=284;

        byte[] bytes=BitConverter.GetBytes(data);
        // bytes[0] = 28
        // bytes[1] = 1
    }
```

Comment: No, he does not want that, but yes, this is the correct way to do it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Why would `284 >> 8` would be `4`?

Why would `284` be split in two bytes equal to `28` and `4`?

The binary representation of `284` is `0000 0001 0001 1100`. As you can see, there are two bytes (eight bits) which are `0000 0001` (`256` in decimal) and `0001 1100` (`28` in decimal).

`284 >> 8` is `1` (`0000 0001`) and it is correct.

`284` should be split in two bytes equal to `256` and `24`.

**You conversion is correct!**

Comment: thanks but that didn't solve or help me in any way i still want to achieve:

byte[0] = 28 (decimal)
byte[1] = 4 (decimal)

in base of a short value.

Comment: In that case, my questions remain open. Why would it be 28 and 4? Why not 2 and 84? What happens to 3284? What is the rule for conversion?

Comment: because 284 means the buffer size, and i need from that buffer the first 2 bytes to indicate the size which is 284...

Comment: That certainly doesn't explain why you don't keep the binary representation or why you divide by 10 to populate the least significant byte.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist:

```
short val = 284;
byte a = (byte)(val / 10);
byte b = (byte)(val % 10);
```

**Disclaimer:**

This does not make much sense, but it is what you want. I assume you want values from 0 to 99. The logical thing to do would be to use 100 as the denominator and not 10. But then again, I have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: What i am doing is sending a packet, the first 2 bytes are used to indicate the packet len. After all the processing the packet size is 284 so the first 2 bytes should be 284 or 0x11C

Comment: As everyone else here already said, you are mixing up hex and dec... short val = 0x284 would give the expected result with your original code.. given that you fail to see this, I suspect you just grabbed that code from somewhere ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Drop the nonsense conversion you are using and go for `System.BitConverter.ToInt16`

```
  //to bytes
  var buffer = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(284); //your short value

  //from bytes
  var value = System.BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 0);
```