# c# reinterpret an array of bytes as an array of shorts

Tags: c#

I would like to duplicate following C logic in C# if possible:

```
void f(unsigned char *byteArr)
{
  short *shArr = (short*)byteArr; // shArr[0] = -8, shArr[1] = -265
}
unsigned char byteArr[4];
byteArr[0] = 248;
byteArr[1] = 255;
byteArr[2] = 247;
byteArr[3] = 254;
f(byteArr);
```

So in C# I have

```
void f(byte[] byteArr)
{
  short[] shArr = ?
}
```

and would like shArr to be `{-8, -265}`. (How) is this possible?

Comment: It very much looks like you are asking about a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about your attempted approach to solve your _real_ problem, explain your _real_ problem. Chances are that there are better C# ways to solve your problem than doing it "C style"...

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/5749858/34092 do what you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Buffer_BlockCopy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

```
var shArr = new short[byteArr.Length / 2];
Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArr, 0, shArr, 0, byteArr.Length);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/b9ZolZ

Answer (score 6):

Apparently you want to reinterpret an array of bytes as an array of shorts.

The easiest way is to use [`Span`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-2.2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] byteArr = new byte[] { 248, 255, 247, 254 };

    Console.WriteLine(byteArr[2]);
    f(byteArr);
    Console.WriteLine(byteArr[2]);
}

private static void f(byte[] byteArr)
{
    Span<short> shArr = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, short>(byteArr);

    shArr[1] = 42;
}
```

However the actual question is whether you [actually need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) to do this in the first place.