# Translating from Java to C# a snippet of ByteBuffer code

Tags: java, c#, binary, memorystream, bytebuffer

I've been trying to translate the following Java code to C#.

```
    // two bytes to make a short (16 bit integer)
private short bytesToShort(byte hi, byte low) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{hi, low}).getShort();
}
```

So far this is what I've managed to put together from searching around:

```
    private short bytesToShort(byte hi, byte low)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

    writer.Write(hi);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Write(low);
    writer.Flush();

    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    
    return reader.ReadInt16();
    
}
```

But I'm getting the *"Unable to read beyond the end of stream"* error. Adding `stream.Position = 0;` after the last `writer.Flush();` fixes that issue but the values I'm getting are not correct. I assume I have more issue with the above code and the `stream.Position = 0;` is not the correct answer even if it seems to fix the issue.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I have two working solutions to this now. The first one is what Andreas posted as an answer below:

```
return (short) (((hi & 0xFF) << 8) | (low & 0xFF));
```

It works like a charm and I think out of the two solutions I have, this is the better one.
The other is:

```
return BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[2] { (byte)low, (byte)hi }, 0);
```

For this one I had to swap the positions of "low" and "hi" in order to get the correct results.

**Important!**
For those translating from Java to C#, there is a very important difference between the Java byte and the C# byte.

Java byte is signed which means it takes values between -128 to 127 but the C# byte is unsigned which takes values between 0 and 255.

If you want to use the Java signed byte in C#, you have to use **sbyte**, this was a detail I was not aware off and it created issues for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749801/converting-2-bytes-to-short-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{hi, low}).getShort()` is the same as:

```java
return (short) (((hi & 0xFF) << 8) | (low & 0xFF));
```

That version is the same in both Java and C#.

Comment: This worked like a charm! While waiting I also found another answer which I will post as an update to my original post.

Comment: @Nick You "found"? I believe [Sweeper found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587779/translating-from-java-to-c-sharp-a-snippet-of-bytebuffer-code/62588238?noredirect=1#comment110682969_62587779) for you.

Comment: You are correct, the solution was based on the link that Sweeper posted.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple in C#. You can use two methods in C#

First is

```
short sh = (short)((hi << 4) | low);
```

Second is you can use Convert.To function like below

```
sh =Convert.ToInt16((hi << 4) | low);
```

This convert is very powerful with many options. You can also explore BitConverter.ToInt16(byte[] array,int index)

Below is working code for console application in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testBitConvertor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte hi = 1;
            byte low = 1;

            // short sh = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte(hi << 8) | low),1);
            short sh = (short)((hi << 4) | low);
            Console.WriteLine(sh);
            sh =Convert.ToInt16((hi << 4) | low);
            Console.WriteLine(sh);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```