# Why does BitConverter seemingly return incorrect results when converting floats and bytes?

Tags: c#, endianness, bitconverter

I'm working in C# and attempting to pack four bytes into a float (the context is game development, where an RGBA color is packed into a single value). To do this, I'm using `BitConverter`, but certain conversions seem to result in incorrect bytes. Take the following example (using bytes `0, 0, 129, 255`):

```
var before = new [] { (byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)129, (byte)255 };
var f = BitConverter.ToSingle(before, 0); // Results in NaN
var after = BitConverter.GetBytes(f); // Results in bytes 0, 0, 193, 255
```

Using https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html, I verified that the four bytes I started with (`0, 0, 129, 255`, equivalent to binary `00000000000000001000000111111111`) represents the floating-point value `4.66338115943e-41`. By flipping the endianness (binary `11111111100000010000000000000000`), I get `NaN` (which matches `f` in the code above). But when I convert that float back to bytes, I get `0, 0, 193, 255` (note `193` when I'm expecting `129`).

Curiously, running this same  example with bytes `0, 0, 128, 255` is correct (the floating-point value `f` becomes `-Infinity`, then converting back to bytes yields `0, 0, 128, 255` again). Given this fact, I suspect `NaN` is relevant.

Can anyone shed some light on what's happening here?

**Update:** the question [Converting 2 bytes to Short in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749801/converting-2-bytes-to-short-in-c-sharp) was listed as a duplicate, but that's inaccurate. That question is attempting to convert bytes to a value (in that case, two bytes to a short) and incorrect endianness was giving an unexpected value. In my case, the actual float value is irrelevant (since I'm not *using* the converted value as a float). Instead, I'm attempting to effectively reinterpret four bytes as a float *directly* by first converting to a float, then converting back. As shown, that back-and-forth sometimes returns different bytes than the ones I sent in.

**Second update:** I'll simply my question. As Peter Duniho comments, `BitConverter` will never *modify* the bytes you pass in, but simply copy them to a new memory location and reinterpret the result. However, as my example shows, it is possible to send in four bytes (`0, 0, 129, 255`) which are internally copied and reinterpreted to a float, then convert that float back to bytes that are *different* than the originals (`0, 0, 193, 255`).

Endianness is frequently mentioned in relation to `BitConverter`. However, in this case, I feel endianness isn't the root issue. When I call `BitConverter.ToSingle`, I pass in an array of four bytes. Those bytes represent some binary (32 bits) which is converted to a float. By changing the endianness *prior to the function call*, all I'm doing is *changing the bits I send into the function*. Regardless of the *value* of those bits, it should be possible to convert them to a float (also 32 bits), then convert the float back to get *the same bits I sent in*. As demonstrated in my example, using bytes `0, 0, 129, 255` (binary `00000000000000001000000111111111`) results in a floating-point value. I'd like to take that value (the float represented by those bits) and convert it to the original four bytes.

Is this possible in C# in all cases?

Comment: It seems to be the byte order which is causing the issue. If you try  `before = { 255, 129, 0, 0 }` you get the expected `4.66338115943e-41` float.

Comment: Are you just using the `float` type as a convenient container for individual bytes, or you are doing organic work with this type as well?

Comment: `BitConverter` byte order can be determined with the `IsLittleEndian` property. As for your specific examples, it's not clear why if you want RGBA values you are using `float` at all, but the basic reason for what you observe is that there are more than one (many more than one) binary values that are treated as either `NaN`, `Infinity`, or `-Infinity`. Keep in mind that endianness affects _byte_ order, but not bit order. When you reversed the _bits_, you did not correct for the endianness issue, but instead just corrupted the value, hence the `193` instead of `129`.

Comment: To clarify, the problem isn't the specific float coming back (I'm not expecting `4.66338115943e-41`). My intent is to effectively reinterpret four bytes as a float directly, such that those bytes (used as RGBA colors) are available while rendering. As for why I'm using floats at all, it's largely a convenience when gathering up data to buffer to the GPU (since many other pieces of data, like position and weighting, are floats).

Comment: _"My intent is to effectively reinterpret four bytes as a float directly"_ -- then you need to respect the endianness of `BitConverter`. See duplicate.

Comment: I still don't think that's the root issue here (the listed duplicate is *not* the same as my question). Even accounting for endianness, couldn't some RGBA bytes end up resulting in the value I used above, such that converting to float and back to bytes would give incorrect results? At the end of the day, I'm attempting to convert 32 bits to a float and back to those same bits. Is this possible in C# in all cases?

Comment: @Grimelios `float` is an alias for `System.Single` which is a value type. Passing your `NaN` value as a parameter to `BitConverter.GetBytes()` passes it by value, rather than reference, which means that the copied value could potentially be initialized with an NaN value using a different bit sequence. As long as the exponent is `FF` and the fraction is non-zero, the `float` will be an NaN. So _no_, converting four bytes to a `float` and back to the original four bytes will not be possible in all cases. As Peter already stated, the motivation for this conversion to float and back is unclear.

Comment: @Patrick: _"converting four bytes to a float and back to the original four bytes will not be possible in all cases"_ -- IMHO this statement is not precisely correct. In particular, while (as noted) there are multiple representations for `NaN`, `BitConverter` does not concern itself with that, nor would any other aspect of code involved in _just_ converting 4 bytes to a `float` and then back again. The 4 bytes passed to `BitConverter` will be copied directly into the `float` value, and then if passed to `BitConverter` again for conversion back to an array, will be copied verbatim back again.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I appreciate you pointing out that `BitConverter` does not concern itself with the fact there are multiple representations for `NaN`. If you actually re-read what I said, I never claimed that it did. _"The 4 bytes passed to `BitConverter` will be copied directly into the `float` value, and then if passed to `BitConverter` again for conversion back to an array, will be copied verbatim back again."_ The fact is, [this isn't really true](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x2ZxJu). Their desired outcome does not match the actual outcome; the exact semantics don't really matter.

Comment: @Patrick: your demo is interesting, given that the .NET source literally ignores the `float` aspect of the value. It actually copies the bytes into an int and uses an unsafe cast to float, and then vice a versa to get the bytes back. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,f44ffc4f294cd463 and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,7d2958fc09cde954. When I write the same code in Visual Studio, I get exactly the result I expect, with the exact bytes round-tripping with no trouble at all. .NET 5 instead of 4.7.2.

Comment: Fwiw Peter, I've been testing on various .Net versions. It seems to fail on every .Net Framework version I've tried (up to 4.8.0), but works on .Net Core (and .Net 5, as you're using). Possible that your code worked for that reason.

Comment: Since it appears in older versions of .NET there is some runtime conversion of the `float` value that is out of `BitConverter`'s control, you'll need to do the conversion yourself, and even then you may run into problems (depending on why the framework is converting the value). Your question really winds up having two parts then, one about the endianness and one about the implicit conversion of `NaN`. ...

Comment: ... See the other duplicate I've added for an answer to how to get a true binary-copying conversion independent of `BitConverter`. If that doesn't work, then nothing will (use `float` instead of `int` as in the answer to that question).

Comment: I also feel it's important to note that, as stated in my updates to the question, endianness is provably *not* an issue in this specific example. The source bytes used (`0, 0, 129, 255`) give binary `00000000000000001000000111111111`. Reversing each byte individually (as you noted above) results in the *same* binary.

Comment: Yes, NaN is one problem.  The standard specifies a bunch of different values for NaN, distinguishing between quiet NaNs and [signaling NaNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Signaling_NaN).  Bad idea and not supported by .NET which only allows a single value for NaN, you're seeing it normalize the value.  Other cases are the distinction between +0 and -0, .NET normalizes to +0.  And denormal values, technically can be flushed to 0 (shouldn't happen).  Only way to get ahead is not do this, BitConverter.ToInt32() doesn't get messed with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After research, experimentation, and discussion with friends, the root cause of this behavior (bytes changing when converted to and from a float) seems to be [signaling vs. quiet NaNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Signaling_NaN) (as Hans Passant also pointed out in a comment). I'm no expert on signaling and quiet NaNs, but from what I understand, **quiet NaNs have the highest-order bit of the mantissa set to one**, while **signaling NaNs have that bit set to zero**. See the following image (taken from https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) for reference. I've drawn four colored boxes around each group of eight bits, as well as an arrow pointing to the highest-order mantissa bit.

[image: Visual representation of a float's bit layout.]

Of course, the question I posted wasn't about floating-point bit layout or signaling vs. quiet NaNs, but simply asking why my encoded bytes were seemingly modified. The answer is that the C# runtime (or at least I *assume* it's the C# runtime) internally **converts all signaling NaNs to quiet**, meaning that **the byte encoded at that position has its second bit swapped from zero to one**.

For example, the bytes `0, 0, 129, 255` (encoded in the reverse order, I think due to endianness) puts the value `129` in the second byte (the green box). `129` in binary is `10000001`, so flipping its second bit gives `11000001`, which is `193` (exactly what I saw in my original example). This same pattern (the encoded byte having its value changed) applies to all bytes in the range `129-191` inclusive. Bytes `128` and lower aren't NaNs, while bytes `192` and higher *are* NaNs, but don't have their value modified because their second bit (placed at the highest-order mantissa bit) is already one.

So that answers *why* this behavior occurs, but in my mind, there are two questions remaining:

1. Is it possible to disable this behavior (converting signaling NaNs to quiet) in C#?
2. If not, what's the workaround?

The answer to the first question seems to be **no** (I'll amend this answer if I learn otherwise). However, it's important to note that this behavior doesn't appear consistent across all .NET versions. On my computer, NaNs *are* converted (i.e. my encoded bytes changed) on every .NET Framework version I tried (starting with 4.8.0, then working back down). NaNs appear to *not* be converted (i.e. my encoded bytes did *not* change) in .NET Core 3 and .NET 5 (I didn't test every available version). In addition, a friend was able to run the same sample code on .NET Framework 4.7.2, and surprisingly, the bytes were *not* modified on his machine. The internals of different C# runtimes isn't my area of expertise, but suffice to say there's variance among versions and computers.

The answer to the second question is to, as others have suggested, **simply avoid the float conversion entirely**. Instead, each set of four bytes (representing RGBA colors in my case) can either be encoded in an integer or added to a byte array directly.

Comment: Maybe due to x86 "flds" which "pushes the argument onto the FPU register stack"; http://troubles.md/i-triple-equals/

Comment: That's probably it, as the source just looks like a bit cast and return https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,332

Comment: Related runtime issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48832